# iOS: Install iPad App wirelessly doesn't work

Tags: ipad, ios5, wireless, software-distribution

I have followed [this](http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/#app43ad871e) precisely to install App wirelessly and also followed different blogs and posts but not able to get enterprise distribution working.

I have done following things.

Index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>My app</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>

    <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://10.0.20.600:5151/MyApp.plist">
            Install App</a>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

MyApp.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>URL</key>
    <string>http://10.0.20.600:5151/MyApp.ipa</string>
    <key>display-image</key>
    <string>http://10.0.20.600:5151/icon72x72.png</string>
    <key>full-size-image</key>
    <string>http://10.0.20.600:5151/icon512x512.png</string>
    <key>bundle-identifier</key>
    <string>com.MyCompany.MyApp</string>
    <key>bundle-version</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>MyAppName</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Enabled MIME types:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ipa" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".plist" mimeType="text/xml" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Given full permissions to MyApp.plist file.

When I open http://10.0.20.600:5151/index.html page on Safari on iPad, I get the page and on clicking Install App, *** It doesn't do anything *** No errors and nothing!

Someone has also mentioned to download mobile provision file so I added following in my index.html

```
<a href="http://10.0.20.600:5151/MyApp.mobileprovision">
            Install Provisioning File</a>
```

..but when I click this it says "File or Directory not found".

Could anyone please tell me what am I missing here? I have spend half day now to get this working!

Comment: What happen when you open: http://10.0.20.600:5151/MyApp.ipa?

Comment: Hmm just did it. It says "Download failed" - "Safari cannot download this file",

Comment: I could see the icon when I open 10.0.20.600:5151/icon72x72.png

Comment: "Download failed",.. thats the issue. What http server you use? First you need to manage that when you open 10.0.20.600:5151/MyApp.ipa that it then download the ipa. The rest looks good.

Comment: It's Windows Server 2008 R2, with IIS 6.0 installed! What do I have to do with this? Thanks.

Comment: Did xcode create your manifest file because it looks like its missing some information?

Comment: Yes I have created it using XCode.

Comment: @JonasSchnelli can you please tell me what could I check on http server please. I am still not able to resolve this issue.

Comment: @JonasSchnelli I have tested downloading IPA file with http://install.diawi.com/app-application/**.ipa and it gives same message "cannot download this file" but it works fine when I point this ipa file in my plist file!

Comment: Moreover, I am able to download ipa file from Chrom browser on my MAC but Safari reporting the issue on iPad!!

Comment: Uff! Finally got this working. Will post my research and answer!

Comment: when will u post ur answer !!!

Comment: I already did on Jun 1 at 11:56 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem.

I've added the MIME types.
I am able to open the icons. Trying to open the ipa on the iPad provides me with the same error as you get. However I can open the ipa from the browser on my PC.

I have followed the steps in this [link](http://www.syndicatedmethods.com/SyndicatedBlogs/post/2011/02/25/Fun-With-Distributing-iPhone-Apps-OTA.aspx), but still when I click the link nothing happens.
Maybe the link will help you even if it does nothing for me?

My manifest file also looks a bit different (not created by xcode btw)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
            <key>items</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://url/to/ipa.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://url/to/icon/57.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://url/to/full/icon.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.app.myapp</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.1</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>myApp</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </plist>
```

Sorry I couldn't be of any more help!

Comment: Cheers mate. I think the plist file was the only issue. It worked now!

Comment: Glad to hear it! What exactly was wrong? I eventually gave up. Any hints would be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: For me this plist file and the download link was the culprits. It wasn't working if I put www prefix....try to open the link in browser and you should be able to download ipa file then use the same link in itms-services.

Comment: I have posted ans for you if that is helpful!

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it another try later :) Fingers crossed ;)

Comment: Awesome! Got it working :) Apparently I was missing some info in the plist file. I copied yours and replaced the urls and tadaaa :D

Comment: @Tinelise The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Following settings always worked for me!

install.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Remote App Install</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>

    <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://us.www.mysite.com/install.plist">
        Install App</a>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

install.plist file

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>items</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
    <key>assets</key>
      <array>
        <dict>
        <key>kind</key>
        <string>software-package</string>
        <key>url</key>
         <string>http://us.www.mysite.com/myapp1_0.ipa</string>
        </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://us.www.mysite.com/icon.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>http://us.www.mysite.com/icon@2x.png</string>
                </dict>
      </array>

             <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
        <key>bundle-identifier</key>
        <string>com.mysite.myapp</string>
        <key>bundle-version</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>kind</key>
        <string>software</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>My App</string>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </array>
 </dict>
```

Comment: I am also getting same problem .Do not we need this line "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" ?.While i am opening file it is showing like not found .But it deployed in dropbox succesfully .

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should try with a `HyperLink` other than using the `A` tag.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the first line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
from your plist file and it should work.